# Protocol security

Tags: protocol-design

[image: Protocol]

This protocol is designed to establish a session key K'AB between two parties without the interaction with a server. In this case, the key KAB is a long-term key shared between Alice and Bob. I am supposed to create an attack, where i imitate Bob. I think it is a problem with the missing verification of Bob. I'm stuck with this task for a couple of days and can't get a proper answer. Please help

Comment: HINT: Is the protocol supposed to work both ways? If so, what happens if you try to set up two sessions, one as initiator and one as responder?

Comment: Do you mean a session where bob acts as initiator?

Comment: Yes, set up two sessions: one where your pretending to be Bob as initiator and one where you're pretending to be Bob as resonder.

Comment: I'm thinking about saving the Nonce of Alice when being a responder and then use the same Nonce initiating. Am I on the right track?

Comment: So if I'm inititing, I get: {NB,K'AB}KAB, N'A. Can I then reuse this information when I am the responder, assuming the Nonces are the same?

Comment: Thanks for your help! I was trying to figure out a way to get the session key somehow, but it was the wrong approach.